# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation : selector-engine.js:41

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-5

I recently upgraded my ASP.NET MVC application to latest bootstrap and jQuery versions. I get the following error when loading up a partial view in a modal.

Screenshot of error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/coAjF.png

The modal doesn't even load.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<a id="btnOpenWidget" class="dropdown-item" 
   href="#" data-bs-target="#divAddCustomWidgetModal" 
   data-bs-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" 
   data-url="@Url.Action(Actions._AddWidget, Controllers.Home, new { Area = string.Empty })">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Open Widget
</a>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="divAddCustomWidgetModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body"></div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[data-bs-target="#divAddCustomWidgetModal"]').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        console.log(url);
        $('#divAddCustomWidgetModal .modal-body').load(url);
    });
});
```

I tried everything out there and it still doesn't work. Earlier the modal div was elsewhere, I even moved it to the current cshtml as the script, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

There must be `.modal-dialog` and `.modal-body` classes on the modal element, so add `.modal-dialog` parent container to `.modal-body`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="divAddCustomWidgetModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-body"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As there is no dialog container, something probably goes wrong here:

> ```
> const modalBody = SelectorEngine.findOne(SELECTOR_MODAL_BODY, this._dialog)
> ```
>
> https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/js/src/modal.js#L181
>
> ```
>  findOne(selector, element = document.documentElement) {
>      return Element.prototype.querySelector.call(element, selector)
>  }
> ```
>
> https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/js/src/dom/selector-engine.js#L41

demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[data-bs-target="#divAddCustomWidgetModal"]').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        console.log(url);
        //$('#divAddCustomWidgetModal .modal-body').load(url);
         $('#divAddCustomWidgetModal .modal-body').load('https://placehold.co/400x200');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<a id="btnOpenWidget" class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-bs-target="#divAddCustomWidgetModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-url="@Url.Action(Actions._AddWidget, Controllers.Home, new { Area = string.Empty })">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Open Widget
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="divAddCustomWidgetModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-body"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```